# HashMap as a get request response Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, deserialization, get-request

I am a noob in Spring Boot and I am trying to make 2 servers to communicate with each other. Each server works individually, but I have a broken communication.

First Server that gets the user requests and sends the get requests to the Server2:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(path = "/webpage")
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private CheckService checkService;

    @Autowired
    private SearchService searchService;

    @Autowired
    private GetDatasetService getDatasetService;

    @GetMapping(path = {"check"})
    public String CheckDataset(@RequestParam List<String> checking) {
        return checkService.checkDataset(checking);
    }


//    @RequestParam List<String> userinfo
    @GetMapping(path = {"GetDataset"})
    public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>> GetDataset(@RequestParam List<String> userinfo) {

        return getDatasetService.getDataset(userinfo);
    }
```

This is the "GetDatasetService" that sends the "Get" request, this does not work:

```
public class GetDatasetService {

    @Value("${first.year.project.url}")
    private String url;


    public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>> getDataset(List<String> userinfo){

        String urlForGetDataset = url + "/api/GetDataset";

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(urlForGetDataset)
                .queryParam("userinfo",userinfo)
                .build(Collections
                        .emptyMap());

        return WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(GetDatasetModel.class)
                .block();

    }
}
```

The "CheckService" works:

```
@Component
public class CheckService {

    @Value("${first.year.project.url}")
    private String url;


    public String checkDataset(List<String> list){
        String urlForrCheck = url + "/api/Check";

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(urlForrCheck)
                .queryParam("checking",list)
                .build(Collections
                        .emptyMap());


        String check = WebClient.create()
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();

        return check;
    }
}
```

Server2

The "RequestController" class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = {"/api"})
public class RequestsController {

    private final HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> DatasetMaps = ProcessingApplication.DatasetMaps;

    @GetMapping(path = {"Check"})
    public String Check(@RequestParam List<String> checking){
        GetCheck getCheck = new GetCheck(this.DatasetMaps);
        CheckModel checkModel = new CheckModel();
        checkModel.setList(checking);
        return getCheck.GetCheckDatasetMethod(checkModel.checking);
    }


    @GetMapping(path = {"GetDataset"})
    public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, List<String>>> GetDataset(@RequestParam List<String> userinfo) throws IOException {

        GetDatasetModel getDatasetModel = new GetDatasetModel();
        getDatasetModel.setList(userinfo);
        GetDataset getDataset = new GetDataset();
        return getDataset.GetDatasetMethod(getDatasetModel.userinfo.get(0),getDatasetModel.userinfo.get(1));
    }
```

The "CheckModel" class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CheckModel {
    protected List<String> checking;
    public CheckModel(){}
    public void setList(List<String> list){
        this.checking = list;
    }
}
```

The "GetDatasetModel" class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class GetDatasetModel {
    protected List<String> userinfo;

    public GetDatasetModel(){}

    public void setList(List<String> userinfo){
        this.userinfo=userinfo;
    }
}
```

As it is presented in the following image the Server2 for the "GetDataset" request is working perfectly.

In the request is returning a nested hashmap, the request is working when I use "Postman".

[image]

When I am trying to use the "GetDataset" using the "Server1" is getting an error.

[image]

The error is quite big and I will just put just a part of it, if you need more I will edit the post:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [map type; class com.Portal.Indexes.HTMLModel.GetDatasetModel, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]]]\n\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:269)\n\tSuppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: \nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://127.0.0.1:1200/api/GetDataset?userinfo=Alex&userinfo=check [DefaultClientResponse]\nOriginal Stack Trace:\n\t\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:269)\n\t\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:209)\n\t\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.lambda$decodeToMono$2(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:189)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:431)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:485)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:712)\n\t\tat reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.
```

Do you know what should I do in this situation?

Comment: You should provide the exception from the log of your service: the image, or your "part of it", is encoded (`\r\n`).

Comment: Also, your are hiding the cause but I'd say that jackson is not processing correctly your JSON as `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>` or expect `GetDatasetModel` to be a `Map`.

Comment: @NoDataFound Hello! Thank you for your comment. Maybe something is encoded, but I did now specified to be encoded.